# How do you use GetDelegateForFunctionPointer to call an external symbol in C# on OSX?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

There are a few people asking around to know how to use the `dl` library to dynamically load and invoke a plugin from C# on non-windows systems.

The advice appears to be, generally speaking, 'use GetDelegateForFunctionPointer'. However, no one can supply an *actually working example* of both *loading* the external library *AND* invoking it.

The following code:

```
class Helper
{
    const int RTLD_NOW = 2;

    [DllImport("dl")]
    static extern IntPtr dlopen([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename, int flags);

    [DllImport("dl")]
    static extern IntPtr dlsym(IntPtr handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string symbol);

    public static void Test() {
        IntPtr libraryHandle = dlopen("libextern.dylib", RTLD_NOW);
        IntPtr action = dlsym(libraryHandle, "rs_trigger");
        var caller = (rs_trigger) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(action, typeof(rs_trigger));
        var r = caller(1);
        log ("Success! " + libraryHandle + " .. " + action + " --> " + r);
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal delegate int rs_trigger(int value);
}
```

Prints:

```
Success! 105553117399168 .. 6120303264 --> 1339432
```

However, the rs_trigger in the c code invoked does not return 1339432. Invoking the library using python and ctypes shows:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan 29 2015, 06:27:40)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.CDLL("libextern.dylib")
>>> lib
<CDLL 'libextern.dylib', handle 7f7f83601e60 at 10b389550>
>>> lib.rs_trigger
<_FuncPtr object at 0x10b367940>
>>> lib.rs_trigger(1)
Trigger called
Invoking callback
No callback bound
101
>>> lib.rs_trigger(100)
Trigger called
Nope
200
>>> output = lib.rs_trigger(100)
Trigger called
Nope
>>> output
200
```

Clearly the C# call `caller(1)` is passing malformed data over to the c function call... but I've read a lot of example in the past hour, and all of them seem to say to do exactly this.

What am I doing wrong?

What *exactly* is the syntax to use for the delegate you define to bind the the IntPtr to to invoke it as an external function call?

(NB. everything is x86_64, that's categorically not the issue)

Here's the c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN64
  #define __EXT __declspec(dllexport)
#elif _WIN32
  #define __EXT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define __EXT extern
#endif

static void (*callback)(int value) = NULL;

__EXT int rs_trigger(int val) {
  printf("Trigger called\n");
  if (val == 1) {
    printf("Invoking callback\n");
    if (callback != NULL) {
      (*callback)(100);
    }
    else {
      printf("No callback bound\n");
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("Nope\n");
  }
  return val + 100;
}

__EXT void rs_register(void *cb) {
  printf("Register called\n");
  callback = cb;
}
```

...and finally, if you're going to down vote the question, please at the very least leave feedback on why this is poor question to ask.

Comment: My psychic debugger says that you are calling a Rust test function.  In which case you mis-declared the function, its return type is *void*, not *int*.  As [visible here](https://github.com/shadowmint/rust-extern/blob/master/test.c).

Comment: I can't answer the question either, but I can tell you this: when someone hazards a guess that doesn't pay off, responding with sarcasm won't encourage others to help. I say this knowing that I've been rude to people too. I don't know about you but I have enough problems without alienating those who might otherwise help, now and in the future.

Comment: @PeterWone I'm really not interested in making this a meta-SO thread about community conduct. I just want an answer to my question.

Comment: This code works for me with both x86 and amd64 builds of mono 3.12.1 on OS X 10.10.2. What version of mono are you using?

Comment: @softwariness mono-3.12.0; the default from 'brew install mono'